# Selecting a specific number of features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

I have a layer with several fields on its table and one of these fields is "population". Is there a way to select **only the top 3 features** with the highest population?
I imagine I need to sort the field in a certain way, but I have tried the "Order by Expression" tool but it doesn't work correctly.
Could it be made by using Python? Any idea?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean when you say "it doesn't work correctly".

Comment: @J.Monticolo , that is exactly what I needed! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the attributes in the attribute table (by clicking the column name) and then select the top 3 directly in the table.